# Is it possible to bring Octave functionality in iOS app?

Tags: ios, c++11, xcode7, octave

I studied about the C++ API provided.Can somebody suggest me some methods or links to proceed

how to import those c files into Xcode and work with it?

Does Octave provide any online API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by downloading the source and following the build instructions. You'll know a lot more when you've done that. The Octave API lets you write plugins for Octave.

Comment: vijay, you mean like this one: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs or like this one: http://octave.org/doxygen/4.0/index.html

Comment: Like this one https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs   @Tasos . Is there any c libraries available like this to use in ios (just like importing those header files and accessing it)

Comment: Thanks for your replies Tasos and John